sudoers rule is listed but not applied
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM that I want to give password-less sudo to a specific user
I created /etc/sudoers.d/user with the content
user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

The user is also on the sudo group so
sudo -l

gives both
(ALL : ALL) ALL
(ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Reading this answer, the NOPASSWD should have worked because it is in /etc/sudoers.d/ but it doesn't, password is still asked

sudoers read :
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d


Did you log off and back on?

What does "work" mean here? What behavior are you expecting and what are you seeing instead?

sudo matches the first entry ("(ALL : ALL) ALL") and stops searching.  Remove the user from the sudo group.
